# How to sort column with null values using display table tag

Tags: java, displaytag

I have list of string values in which some contain null values while sorting these values through display:tag,
I have to first display  those  values  which not contain null values in ascending order and after that
i have to show null values .
Currently i am using following code :

```
<display:column title="Name" property="sName" sortable="true"></display:column>
```

Comment: Nice question, but we can sort only null values first and after that values which contains as not null, +1 and starred

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<display:table ... defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending">
```

where "1" is index of your column.

Comment: Actually I have not to display default sorting ; After first click on column sName(property) , I have to display first all not null values in ascending order after that I have to display all null values ; Thanks for your support .